# How is iOS updating all my apps without permission?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, permission, auto-update

iPad is at iOS 12.3, iPad is WiFi only. iPhone is at iOS 12.4.

Both have got *automatic download and updates* turned OFF in settings → iTunes and AppStore. Yet in the last weeks both devices, without intervention or permission have updated every single App. This has resulted in ADS (apple disorientation services), where I have to login to apps again with passwords I haven’t used for years, and everything’s looking different and working differently. How has this happened?

I do iOS updates for security, but if my App ain’t broke I don’t wanna fix it. How do I stop this app auto-update feature on my iOS devices?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  That is weird for sure. for a preventive measure, turn off "Cellular" below the Auto update setting you mentioned. Don't know about Wi-Fi

Comment: It is called “use mobile data” on my iPhone. IPad is WiFi only.  And the iPad has updated several apps today. IPhone 3 days ago. Still can’t see how this has happened. Several apps I REALLY didn’t want to update as I knew there were problems with the updates.  No way to revert.  Can’t get into some apps asking for passwords. Beginning to hate Apple.

Comment: @Dave45 I think you're directing your anger the wrong place. Apple is not updating your apps without permission - that's not how this works. If you have automatic updates turned off - it won't automatically update. Therefore you need to look at other possibilities - did anyone else use your iPad in that week? - is it a managed device issued by an employer or similar? - could you have turned automatic updates on briefly and forgotten about it? have you inadvertently pressed the update button yourself (or perhaps a pet?)

Comment: @Dave45 For work purposes we have dozens of iPads and iPhones set to not automatically update anything - that has been working without any problems for several years.

Comment: FWIW something similar happened to me about 5 years ago with another iOS upgrade.  I checked all the settings and made sure no apps were set to be upgraded coz I knew there would be a problem with one. After the upgrade was complete, guess what?  all my apps had been upgraded, including one mapping app that had been "upgraded" from my pay-for £25 edition to the "free edition" losing my ability to import from my CDs, causing me no end of pain. If I was to guess I'd say an iOS upgrade resets defaults to update apps automatically. Which they quietly fix a few days later.

Comment: @jksoegaard - No pets, I hate upgrades so would never knowingly do it, it happened on two devices, nobody else uses my ipad.... spooky. These devices don't seem to be under my control.  Or I've missed a setting somewhere.

Comment: @Dave45 And you're sure you did not update the iOS in between? Or restore from backup? .... I work with a lot of iOS developers that have automatic updates disabled (for obvious reasons) on lots of devices used for testing - we have not once experienced anything updating by itself.

Comment: I allow iOS updates, so yes it could be that. I don't know how to restore from backup or even if I have any! (my iCloud is full on the iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this just happened to me. Had auto updates turned off, kinda freaked me out. Turned out, in my case, I had enabled “offload unused apps” to free up space - got a feeling this might be why all my apps needed re-downloading. Not sure if “re-downloading” == “upgrade”.